Horse racing margin calculation
Im looking for a formula to an outcome of a chosen margin percentage(300% in example below) to determine the percentage needed to multiple winner odds to?
eg.
if odds for a race winner is 1.65,8,10,13,17,34,81 converted to a probability of 60.6%,12.5%,10%,7.6%,5.88%,2.94%,1.23% with a total % of 100.15%.
if I multiply each odd by 21% it will result in a total margin percentage of 232.6%.
if I wanted an outcome of 300% what would the required percentage be ?

Required percentage = $\frac {300} {total }$$-100$
